# is it good practice for DTOs returned in @RestController to implement Serializable?

Tags: java, spring, serializable

I noticed in many spring projects that some of the DTOs are trying to implement Serializable interface, so far as I know, the serialization process is done via Spring automatically under the hood making use of fastjson and so on, so what difference does implementing Serializable make ? is it necessary or is it good practice ?

Comment: "is it necessary [...]?" that can be tested by omitting it and seeing if everything still works. By the way, no, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Serializable is a Java 1.0 legacy marker interface.  It's neither necessary nor good practice now.  It used to be the way to serialize a class to byte code.  I would say serializing to XML, JSON, or protobuf are better choices.

Comment: I would call data transfer object another failed J2EE "best practice".

Comment: so it is totally unnecessary ? @duffymo

Comment: Unnecessary.  You should only be worried about your projects, of course.  What does it matter what others do?